# Raw sql query text in .net

Tags: .net, sql

Is it possible to get somehow the query text, that SqlCommand generates?

Comment: In what context? The developer is usually the person setting the query text via `CommandText`, so you can normally just log that before or after assigning it to the command.

Comment: Are you not already initialising SqlCommand.CommandText?

Comment: I assume for the following kind of reason: if CommandType = StoredProcedure, then CommandText is just the sproc name. If it has a number of parameters, then presumably you want the actual EXECUTE statement that will be executed (i.e. something you can copy n paste into SSMS). Can you confirm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run Sql Server Profiler and connect to the Sql Server to eavesdrop on the communication.